# Cannot use my objects method when accessing from Stage LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a class `Card` with the method `setOwner`. I have set up my touch input to use a `hitActor` to identify touches by getting the `Actor`'s name like so :

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
   Vector2 hitCoord = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2((float) screenX, (float) screenY));
   Actor hitActor = stage.hit(hitCoord.x, hitCoord.y, false);
    if (hitActor != null) {
            stage.getRoot().findActor(hitActor.getName()).setOwner();// here it doesnt identify the setOwner() method;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't identify the method `setOwner()`.
My `Card` actors are in a ListArray `deck` so I type casted them like so :

```
  for (Card c : deck) {
        c = (Card) stage.getRoot().findActor(c.getName() + c.getSuit());
    }
```

But still it doesn't identify the methods declared in the `Card` class. My goal is to call the method`setOwner` on the `Actor` that got touched.

Comment: Perhaps you should simply attach listeners to the actors instead of the stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your `Card` class extends `Actor`, but since `setOwner` only exists on `Card` you can't call it without casting the `Actor` to a `Card` first.

Also, since the hit test returns an `Actor` you shouldn't have to ask the `Stage` for it by name using the `findActor` method.

Consider changing your code to something like this;

```
if (hitActor != null && hitActor instanceof Card) {
    ((Card)hitActor).setOwner ();
}
```

Comment: It worked ! Could you please point me to some read material ,so that I can understand what happens better? @bornander